# Is the LLVM 5.0 compiler equivalent to the GCC compiler?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

I have to write my projects for class in ISO C++ or C++/CLI and while the professor explains how to accomplish this in Windows, it is very difficult to know how to setup the equivalent on my Mac.  I am currently running xCode 5.0.2 and it seems to compile the sample applications with no problem using the LLVM 5.0 compiler.  I've read that Apple no longer supports GCC compiler, so my question is are the two compilers equivalent?  Will code that runs in GCC compiler also work in the LLVM 5.0 compiler?

Comment: Various compilers can have incompatible language extensions, but if you stick to the standard, you should not worry about this. GCC and Clang are pretty good at complying with the standard.

Comment: To extend the comment from SirDarius, Clang implements some of the extensions of GCC as well, maybe even enough to compile the Linux kernel source (which uses quite a few GCC extensions)? In fact, the Intel C compiler was deliberately implementing many of the GCC extensions just to be able to compile the Linux kernel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no LLVM 5.0. The LLVM project is currently at version 3.4. The Apple LLVM/Clang variant shipped with XCode 5 may carry a version number that corresponds to the XCode version, but that is mildly misleading.

That said, yes, most stuff that works with GCC 4.2 (the last one that Apple shipped) will work just fine with LLVM/Clang.

C++/CLI, on the other hand, is a Microsoft-proprietary thing and you will not be able to use it on a Mac no matter what, and neither GCC nor Clang support it.

Answer (score 0):

> Will code that runs in GCC compiler also work in the LLVM 5.0
>   compiler?

If by "runs" you mean "compiles," then yes, assuming your code is Standard-compliant.

Weather or not your code is Standard-complliant depends, in part, on how well your professor is doing his job.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly. Being compatible with GCC is one of Clang's primary goals (see http://clang.llvm.org/features.html#gcccompat ). That said, you can install gcc via MacPorts, http://www.macports.org/ if you really need it.